# How to resample audio with AudioCodec?

Tags: android, audio, wav, android-mediacodec

I have `PCM` audio data with sample rate 48000, I want to encode audio to `AAC` with sample rate 44100? Is it possible to do so with `MediaCodec`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that `MediaCodec` API doesn't support resampling (to this day). You would need to either do this manually or use a library (e.g. Oboe, Sonic).